# Cannot add further co-administrators using Microsoft account when SSO also configured

Tags: azure

We have a number of Azure subscriptions with various co-administrators in our environment. To date, we have used people's Microsoft accounts to grant co-administrator rights, and of course many use their corporate [username]@[company domain] email address for these.

Some time ago, we enabled Azure directory, synchronized to our on-premise AD, where accounts have also been @ - and all was good. When adding new co-admins, we simply had to choose if we wanted to use their MS account or their organizational account.

However, we're now seeing the following error when adding *some* users' Microsoft accounts to *some* subscriptions:

> The Microsoft Account '[username]@[company domain]' cannot be made a co-administrator as its domain is the same as one of the Verified Domains of the target subscription's directory.

Has anyone else seen this - is it an intentional change in behaviour? It seems somewhat inconsistent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft support, this change in behavior is intentional.

(Since posting the question, they have also sent email notifications that any co-admins with Microsoft accounts outside of the Azure Directory will be added as guest accounts in the subscription's directory.)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, then I used the new preview portal and it worked.
try it out